# How do I ensure that my bootstrap layout is the right size on a mobile phone?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, openlayers

I'm trying to build a page with a navbar on top and a full screen open layers map underneath.  There's also an off page navigation pane that slides in when the hamburger glyph is clicked.

I got the layout how I want it on my laptop screen, but when I checked on my phone, the navbar and fonts are far too small.  Am I missing something in bootstrap to make this work?  Is it the fault of the openlayers CSS?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk1Sj.jpg)
Live: http://carpiediem.github.io/quartermaester/

Comment: The root cause seems to be the DPI of my phone.  THe navbar is being rendered at 50px tall, just as it is on my laptop.  That's plenty if I'm using a mouse, but way too small for a browser window that is 1391px covering only a few inches.  I know bootstrap is supposed to handle this; I assume I just set something a little wrong...

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction:               <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You applied `body {font-size: 80%;}`. Either remove or write class for the menu in media-query.

Comment: That didn't make a difference (at least not on my phone).  It looks like Chrome on my phone doesn't trigger the (max-width: 25em) condition.

Comment: Check with other system/phones- browsers, Also try in Mozilla Firefox 'responsive design' mode.